# Wired connection periodically disconnects requires ipconfig /release and /renew to reconnect

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, dhcp

I just got back into University and after a day of using the internet I suddenly was unable to visit other webpages even though I was still able to chat. I restarted the computer and the internet could no longer visit webpages at all. I got a DNS error from the browser (chrome) and the troubleshooter.

The connection comes up as "Network 3" even though It was "Network 2" when it worked. I compared ipconfig /all logs and they seemed identical when it was and was not working.

I've found two ways to get internet connection (they no longer work):

- run ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew several times
- set a random address and have the troubleshooter fix the new found
  dhcp problem (before it says dns cannot fix). I checked and it said
  DHCP was enabled.

But either step one or two usually needs to be repeated several times before the network will change back to "network 2" from the defunct "network 3" and after an hour or so I have problems again.

I've tried:

- Uninstalling windows defender and turning off firewall (windows
  firewall).
- Updating Qualcomm Ethernet driver - it is up to date.
- System Restore (problem resurfaces quickly...it's possible this has
  something to do with windows update?)
- Flushing dns and setting dns myself (google one and others).
- Booting in safe mode with networking...didn't fix anything
- Reinstalling Ethernet Driver
- Using other ethernet cable, other wall port.

I'm out of ideas.

Ipconfig /all:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : NGoller
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Home

Ethernet adapter UConnect:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 90-2B-34-50-33-F4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd00::2086:628:f0a1:73c3(Preferred) 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd00::c86b:370:b1d9:bd73(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2086:628:f0a1:73c3%11(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.33(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, August 28, 2013 11:58:37 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 29, 2013 11:58:37 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.Home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I'm getting these errors commonly:

```
The IP address lease 155.97.227.199 for the Network Card with network address 0x902B345033F4 has been denied by the DHCP server 10.0.1.1 (The DHCP Server sent a DHCPNACK message).

Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.
```

By the way, Operating System: Windows 7 - 64 Bit. Have downloaded latest windows updates.

*Update:*
And my two fixes don't work any more :( .

This is now what happens when I try to Ipconfig /renew:

```
C:\Users\Nikko\Desktop>ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration

An error occurred while renewing interface Local Area Connection : The name spec
ified in the network control block (NCB) is in use on a remote adapter.
The NCB is the data.

An error occurred while releasing interface Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 : The sy
stem cannot find the file specified.
```

*Update 2:*
 So my internet is randomly working again today. The IP address I had before was a local one while the university address should start with 155...

I didn't do anything to the settings...it's bizarre that it all of a sudden works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly enough, I don't think it was a problem on my end and I don't know how it was fixed, it just sort of worked again after around ten days.

Sorry...

Comment: It sounds like your ISP was having DNS issues, or your router was misbehaving. If that happens again, go to adapter settings -> properties -> IPv4 and set manual DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (that's Google's public DNS service, it works very well). My ISP has very unreliable DNS and I use those almost exclusively. https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/ Another possible fix is to reboot your router, some cheap routers (especially the free ones many ISPs give away; *especially* Linksys and Netgear consumer-grade) have issues if left running for long periods of time.

Comment: I did set the manual DNS servers to no avail. It's a big university system. Maybe it would have been enough to reset the router...I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

So you can chat but can't browse and get dns errors when you release/renew?

I can think of 2 possibilities: using a proxy (or the wrong proxy), or the DNS client is stopped.

**In Chrome**: Check Settings > Advanced Settings > Change proxy settings > LAN settings > Uncheck "use a proxy" (or double-check the number if the university server uses one).

If it's already unchecked, it's not a proxy problem.

Go to **Services** (the quickest way just type `services.msc` in search box of start menu) and look for **DNS Client**. Startup type should be *automatic*, status should be *started*. If not, click on **DNS Client**, select automatic in drop down, apply, then start and OK. If it won't start, then go to dependency tab and do the same thing with the other services, just work your way back to the problem.

If DNS is already started, I'm not sure what else it could be, **Device Manager** always says drivers are up to date, but you could look up the actual date of newest driver on the manufacturer's website. Maybe completely uninstalling NIC and drivers, then installing your new ones, but I'd do that as a last resort.

Comment: So first time problem came up I could still chat but not view other websites. The release/renew actually makes it work for a while (well sometimes I have to do it several times). What is the dependency tab? Otherwise I tried what you suggested and no luck.